# Javascript call function when asynchronous conditions are met

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I am using a library called [Papa Parse](http://papaparse.com/) that allows me to load CSV files as JSON files. The library allows me to run a callback once the file has finished loading. However I am not sure what the best method is to run a callback when two required files have finished loading.

This must be a common thing in javascript when multiple resources are need before a method can run. Because the files can be loading asynchronously there is no guarantee of the order they will finish loading. So I would need a way of testing if all conditions are met before the method can run.

Is there a commonly used pattern to do this?

Comment: Promises. (or, if you're using jQuery, `$.Deferred`)

Comment: Or the async library: https://github.com/caolan/async

Comment: This is what you are looking for: [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

Comment: to get an exact answer you need to post some code example of what you are doing.. but in general.. as Stephen said.. Promises..

Comment: It should be noted that Promises are not natively supported in **any** version of IE, and `jQuery.Deferred` has a number of drawbacks. I'd suggest using [bluebird](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bluebird).